# How to create a Maven project from an existing folder structure?

Tags: java, maven

I started a Java project without using any project manager, because I didn't know about them and also I don't really like any of the IDE that are out there. But then I discovered Maven and that VSCode, which is the editor I'm using now, supports it, and I thought that this tool might be handy to debug, run and build my project. So I thought that it would be a good idea to use this tool to manage my project. The problem is that this project is in a pretty advanced state, so I can't afford to start it over right now, and I couldn't find the way to make maven use the folder structure that I want. So my question is how can I force maven to use a folder structure that I want.

Comment: You have to edit sourceDirectory, testSourceDirectory and if you have resources directories in your pom.xml file. But just be sure you have nice reasons to edit standard directory structure. For more information you can reference here: [link]https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Comment: Why not just relocate your files to the maven standard locations like `src/main/java`. It will be far easier in the long run than making a bespoke layout. https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Comment: I strongly recommend to follow the convention over configuration paradigm and change the folder structures according to Maven default layout. This will make it easier to migrate to and also support from tools etc.